# How can I add an 'if' statement in a dataframe so that I check there are rows so I don't run into an indexing error?

Tags: python, dataframe

So I have the following pandas dataframe query:

```
has_primary_reopen = market_info.loc[before_primary_close, "market_state"].iloc[-1] == 'CTS'
```

For the above, I am getting an indexing error, because

```
market_info.loc[before_primary_close, "market_state"]
```

returns an empty dataframe.

So I want to add an `if` statement to check that if the above returns an empty dataframe, then don't execute the top query.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, it's hard to comment without knowing what `market_info` and `before_primary_close` are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
if not market_info.loc[before_primary_close, "market_state"].empty:
    has_primary_reopen = market_info.loc[before_primary_close, "market_state"].iloc[-1] == 'CTS'
```